# Starting and publishing a React Native project with CRNA

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

I am really new to React Native, but I am familiar with React. 
I am interested in hearing the best ways of creating a new React-Native project and ways of publishing it to the app and play store, as well as pros and cons of each method.

I have tried two methods currently, `create-react-native-app` and building a new project through expo XDE.

With both these methods they run the app through the expo app in the Xcode simulator.

From what I understand developing through the expo app is great for 
the development process, but since its not being run completely "natively" on the ios simulator there is a process to make it a "Standalone" app and not just a expo app.

What are the most convenient ways to create a React-Native app that can be developed with keeping publishing to the app and play store in mind?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to create a react native project with native code is `react-native init project-name`.

For that first you have to install react native by `npm install -g react-native-cli`

If you created the project in this way the app runs on Xcode simulator without expo app.

To run the app in ios simulator use `react-native run-ios`.

It automatically create the app as standalone app, no process is need to convert the app as standalone.

I have shared the information AFAIK.

If you want more information kindly visit it [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

In that page select **Building Projects with Native code**

Comment: Thanks! this is what I was looking for!